# ULID native support in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Does PostgreSQL support [Unique Lexicographically Sortable Identifier (ULID)](https://github.com/ulid/spec)  generator out of the box?

It seems not. Does anyone know the best extension implementing such generator?

Comment: By the way, here is an [open proposal to the IETF](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format-00) for adding a “Version 6” to the [UUID spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122). This seems to have similar aims as your ULID. See the [author’s discussion](http://gh.peabody.io/uuidv6/). Implementations available in various programming languages.

Comment: see also [related question](https://github.com/ulid/spec/issues/41) on github

Comment: Lates version of the UUID6 draft https://uuid6.github.io/uuid6-ietf-draft/

Comment: see https://github.com/pksunkara/pgx_ulid

Comment: This proposal expired on Dec 25, 2022.